# Show time picker after cheking check box, rails (Redmine)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on adding date time picker to the Redmine plugin.
I have successfully added it, but now I wanna the time picker must be enable if the check box is  checked, else date picker should be visible by default.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {


    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $( "#leave_leave_end_date" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        minDate: '0',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        useTimeDropdown: true
            });
                } 
                else {
            $( "#leave_leave_end_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        minDate: '0',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        useTimeDropdown: true
            });


            }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#leave_leave_end_date" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        minDate: '0',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        useTimeDropdown: true
            });

 });
```

Keep time picker on doc ready and write code onchange of checkbox to hide/show

```
if($('#checkbox_id').attr('checked'))
{
    //alert ("checked");
    $('#leave_leave_end_date').attr('disabled', false);
} else {
            $('#leave_leave_end_date').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: hey @shemeermali, actually you not got my question correctly.
date picker should be viewable by default, and if I check it as half day i.e. check box it must show date time picker to enter time also.